# Sufficiency of $S=\min\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ when $X \thicksim Pa(\lambda,\theta)$

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, maximum-likelihood

## **Warning**

The question is the sequel to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/602774/finding-the-distribution-of-x-conditional-on-the-event-x-psi) and it was divided into three parts.

The first is this, while the second part is found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/602961/mle-of-the-pareto-parameter-theta-and-unbiasedness).

## **Exercise**

Let $X \thicksim Pa(\lambda, \theta$) with density function
$
f(x; \theta, \lambda) = \frac{\lambda \theta^{\lambda}}{x^{\lambda+1}}
$
where $x \geq \theta$, $\lambda > 0$ and $\theta > 0$.

The CDF is:
$
F(x) = 1 - \left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{\lambda}
$

Let $\lambda$ known. Show if the statistic $S = \min\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ is sufficient for $\theta$ and valuate if it's minimal.

## **Try**

First, I determine the CDF and the density of $S=X_{(1)}$:

$$
F_S(x) = 1 - \left[1 - F(x)\right]^n = 1 - \left[ 1 - 1 + \left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{\lambda} \right]^n = 1 - \left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{n\lambda}
$$

$$
f_S(x) = n\left[ 1 - F(x) \right]^{n-1} f(x) = \frac{n\lambda \theta^{\lambda}}{x^{\lambda+1}} \left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{\lambda(n-1)} = \frac{n\lambda \theta^{n\lambda}}{x^{n\lambda+1}}
$$

The statistic $S \thicksim Pa(n\lambda, \theta)$.

I apply the factorization theorem for sufficiency:
$$
f(x;\theta)  = \prod^{n}_{i=0} \frac{n\lambda \theta^{n\lambda}}{x^{n\lambda+1}_i}
= (n\lambda)^n \theta^{n\lambda} \theta^{n^2 \lambda} \prod^{n}_{i=0} x^{-(n\lambda+1)} = g(x; \theta) \cdot h(x)
$$

$$
g(x; \theta) = (n\lambda)^n \theta^{n\lambda} \theta^{n^2 \lambda} \qquad ; \qquad h(x) = \prod^{n}_{i=0} x^{-(n\lambda+1)}
$$

It's sufficient. I verify the status of minimal using Lehmann-Scheffé theorem:

- $ f(x;\theta) = (n\lambda)^n \theta^{n\lambda} \theta^{n^2 \lambda} \prod^{n}_{i=0} x^{-(n\lambda+1)} $
- $f(y; \theta) = (n\lambda)^n \theta^{n\lambda} \theta^{n^2 \lambda} \prod^{n}_{i=0} y^{-(n\lambda+1)}$

Then:
$$
\frac{L(\theta; x)}{L(\theta; y)} \propto \frac{(n\lambda)^n \theta^{n\lambda} \theta^{n^2 \lambda} \prod^{n}_{i=0} x^{-(n\lambda+1)}}{(n\lambda)^n \theta^{n\lambda} \theta^{n^2 \lambda} \prod^{n}_{i=0} y^{-(n\lambda+1)}} = \frac{\prod^{n}_{i=0} x^{-(n\lambda+1)}}{\prod^{n}_{i=0} y^{-(n\lambda+1)}} = c(X;Y)
$$

It's also minimal.

If I have missed anything else, please report it to me immediately.

Comment: In your step 2, you calculate $\mathbb{E}\hat{\theta}$ using the density function of $x$, but $\hat{\theta} = x_{(1)}$, not $x$.

Comment: Actually, returning to this question, you did the same thing in step 3.

Comment: @jbowman Hi. Should I have used the density function of minimum $f_S(x)$? By virtue of that, it affects step 3, right?

Comment: And step 2; you should be able to see by inspection that the distribution of $x_{(1)}$ is Pareto with parameters $(\theta, n\lambda)$, and as a consequence see what the bias and $c$ are.  Note that your bias term implies that $\hat{\theta}$ is inconsistent, but the correct bias term does not.

Comment: @jbowman You're right. Infact I have found a same question with $\lambda = 2$: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/431173/how-do-i-show-the-mle-is-biased/431184#431184 which I should have used just the density function of the minimum. My question we could define it as a general case. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Yes, it is true for the general case.

Comment: This is three separate questions and, as such, still is not sufficiently focused to be suitable here.

Comment: @whuber Ah, okay. I will arrange to divide the question above into three parts and bring back the respective links. Thank you.

Comment: @whuber I have splitted the question above into three parts.

Comment: @jbowman if you're interested again you can continue to discuss into second part.